# Anyone have deployment rails experience on digital ocean assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, digital-ocean

I have this web application written in ruby on rails with carrierwave function which means I have a picture uploading feature.

If I use heroku I will need to store the media assets on amazon s3. Does digital ocean host static media?

I believe digital ocean is the cheapest option when it comes to hosting and its really fast too.

I am a mac os person.

How does digital ocean work? I can't find relevant tutorial about deployment of rails on digital ocean because its relatively new. Are there relevant information besides the q and a/community/articles on digitalocean.com. Do you need to do it in a linux environment? I am just trying to gather the correct materials at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey typically you need to build your linux setup first with all the proper libraries to deploy you rails app. I use a build similar to this for rails by deploying with capistrano. [This Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) will help you get your linux environment up and running! You might want to supplement that with [linode's securing your server primer](https://library.linode.com/securing-your-server)

Also, Carrierwave works well with [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) if you also want to stay with S3 for your media storage.

Comment: I finally finished the deployment process but my app is not fully working yet, how do you access digital ocean's log ?

Comment: What exactly is the issue (any specific error messages?) with your app? Are you having trouble deploying? Or when you're accessing the app via the browser?

Comment: its ok I was just looking for the production log turns out that its in one of the folders created after launch.